# Why is there no maven resteasy-jaxrs package for version 4.2.0?

Tags: jboss, resteasy

Last release I see in maven for `resteasy-jaxrs` is 3.8.1. When trying to upgrade `resteasy-client` to 4.2.0 there is a dependency in there on `resteasy-jaxrs:4.2.0`:

`org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.getClientInitializedResteasyProviderFactory`.

This dependency is not listed in the `pom` and also it hasn't been published anywhere that I can see...only thing I see is `resteasy-jaxrs-all` which has a lot more `jars` than I want.

Are we not supposed to be using the `resteasy-jaxrs` package anymore?

Comment: I see it on Maven Central https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.jboss.resteasy%20AND%20a:resteasy-client&core=gav. WildFly is at 3.8.1 if you're using the client against WildFly.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins: Your link is to `resteasy-client`, not `resteasy-jaxrs`. The latest versions for all of resteasy is now 4.4.1, but `resteasy-jaxrs` is still `4.0.0.Beta` or `3.9.3.Final`.

Answer (score 6):

In the [RESTEasy 4 is coming soon](https://developer.jboss.org/en/resteasy/blog/2019/03/28/resteasy-4-is-coming-soon) blog post, they explain:

> `esteasy-jaxrs` and `resteasy-client` modules have been split into `resteasy-core-spi`, `resteasy-client-api`, `resteasy-core` and `resteasy-client`, with the first and second ones to be considered as public modules.

But `resteasy-jaxrs` is still in the docs, even when some some fixes where done for 4.4.2.Final released on 2019-12-19.

My project builds just fine after switching to `resteasy-core-spi` or `resteasy-core`.

Answer (score 0):

On mvn central repository you can download resteasy 4.0.0, which is beta:

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs
```

The following versions of RESTEasy were integrated in JBoss:

```
    JBoss      RESTEasy
For  7.2     ~ 3.6.1.SP2
For  7.1     ~ 3.0.26.Final     
For  7.0     ~ 3.0.19.SP5
```

Regards,

Comment: The latest versions for all of resteasy is now `4.4.1`, but `resteasy-jaxrs` is still `4.0.0.Beta` or `3.9.3.Final`.